# C# Parallel.ForEach does not use the available CPU power

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am running an application on a four core machine and it maxes out at around 14% CPU usage and stays there rather constantly.

```
Parallel.ForEach(pages,
    new ParallelOptions { },
      page =>
      {
         // do some CPU intensive stuff
      });
```

Only if I start several instances of the application do I get over 14%. By doing that I can get close to 100% in total.

**Why doesn't Parallel.ForEach do the task parallel enough to use all of the CPU?**

I am running C# .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: Post the loop body. It's 99% one of the typical mistakes which are too small work items, too big ones or synchronization.

Comment: Parallelism will not take yourr CPU usage higher, it will divide the work between the cores, so you shouldn't look at usage per se, but if the app is using every cpu core.

Comment: @bateloche what's the point in using multiple cores if you are not going any faster? The point of parallelism *is* to take your CPU usage higher.